# How to traverse an Array of Objects with multiple elements to make a new array with only the duplicates using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

So, here's my situation:

I have an array of objects, there are 3300+ of them and it could be less or more.

I'm getting it just fine and now, I want to take and SCAN that array of objects, and find all the DUPLICATE markets and make a NEW array with just 1 of the many elements in that array of objects.

Here's an dumbed down example of the many objects:

```
[{
  "EL1": "",
  "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
  "MARKET": "IL",
  "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
  "EL4": "A:B::1243",
  "EL5": "ADFD"
},{
  "EL1": "",
  "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
  "MARKET": "CA",
  "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
  "EL4": "A:B::1243",
  "EL5": "ADFD"
},{
  "EL1": "",
  "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
  "MARKET": "ATLANTA GA",
  "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
  "EL4": "A:B::1243",
  "EL5": "ADFD"
},{
  "EL1": "",
  "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
  "MARKET": "ATLANTA GA",
  "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
  "EL4": "A:B::1243",
  "EL5": "ADFD"
},{
  "EL1": "",
  "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
  "MARKET": "REGION 5",
  "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
  "EL4": "A:B::1243",
  "EL5": "ADFD"
},{
  "EL1": "",
  "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
  "MARKET": "REGION 5",
  "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
  "EL4": "A:B::1243",
  "EL5": "ADFD"
}]
```

What I want is a new array that just returns in Alphabetical Order:

```
["ATLANTA GA", "CA", "IL", "REGION 5"]
```

Here's my code thus far:

```
        $scope.nestAssociation = (arr) => {

            let newArr = JSON.parse(arr);

            // console.log("incoming array: ", newArr);

            const uniqueMarketNames = $scope._.uniqBy(newArr.message, 'MARKET'); // removed if had duplicate id
            // TRIED THIS...  
            // const uniqueMarkets = _.uniqWith(
            //  newArr.message,
            //  (MarketsAll) =>
            //    MarketsAll === newArr.message.MARKET
            // );
            
            let uniqueMarkets = $scope._.uniqBy(newArr, function(elem) {
                return JSON.stringify(_.pick(elem, ['a', 'b']));
            });

            console.log("Unique Market names: ", uniqueMarketNames);
            console.log("Unique Markets: ", uniqueMarkets);

            return uniqueMarkets;
        }
```

What I got is the ENTIRE BLOCK of objects along with 12 of the duplicates out of 3300+ objects.

So, it's working but not, giving me JUST the MARKET

Comment: please define *duplicate*. from the actual data you want all `MARKET` values as unique value in the result array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was what worked for me.

```
        $scope.nestAssociation = (arr) => {

            let newArr = JSON.parse(arr);

            const uniqueMarketNames = $scope._.uniqBy(newArr.message, 'MARKET'); // removed if had duplicate id

            let newMarketArray = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < uniqueMarketNames.length; i++) {
                newMarketArray.push(uniqueMarketNames[i].MARKET);
            }

            console.log("MARKETS: ", newMarketArray);

            return newMarketArray;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// mock data
const newArr = {
  message: [{
    "EL1": "",
    "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
    "MARKET": "IL",
    "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
    "EL4": "A:B::1243",
    "EL5": "ADFD"
  },{
    "EL1": "",
    "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
    "MARKET": "CA",
    "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
    "EL4": "A:B::1243",
    "EL5": "ADFD"
  },{
    "EL1": "",
    "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
    "MARKET": "ATLANTA GA",
    "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
    "EL4": "A:B::1243",
    "EL5": "ADFD"
  },{
    "EL1": "",
    "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
    "MARKET": "ATLANTA GA",
    "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
    "EL4": "A:B::1243",
    "EL5": "ADFD"
  },{
    "EL1": "",
    "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
    "MARKET": "REGION 5",
    "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
    "EL4": "A:B::1243",
    "EL5": "ADFD"
  },{
    "EL1": "",
    "EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
    "MARKET": "REGION 5",
    "EL3": "CHCHILJH",
    "EL4": "A:B::1243",
    "EL5": "ADFD"
  }]
 };
 
 const uniqueMarkets =
   // convert Set to array
   Array.from(
    new Set(
      // extract markets
      newArr
        .message
        .map(({ MARKET }) => MARKET))
   )
   .sort(); // sort alphabetically 
 
 console.log(uniqueMarkets);
```

Comment: I gotta say, who do I vote for? Mine used FOR() and yours Mr. Hudson, works PERFECTLY and yatinsingla works too... but I'm going with Mr. Hudson's. THANK YOU for everyone's support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using Lodash (uniq and map) and Javascript sort:

// arr = [{
"EL1": "",
"EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
"MARKET": "IL",
"EL3": "CHCHILJH",
"EL4": "A:B::1243",
"EL5": "ADFD"
},{
"EL1": "",
"EL2": "ASDGFDSFFE 1:15",
"MARKET": "CA",
"EL3": "CHCHILJH",
"EL4": "A:B::1243",
"EL5": "ADFD"
}]

```
_.uniq(_.map(arr, 'MARKET')).sort()
```